# Node.js terminates execution before script is finished, connecting via socket.io-client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to connect to a third party socket.io site with Node.js. I have installed socket.io-client. However, when I type "node script.js", it terminates after a split second.

This is my pretty simple code:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
socket = io.connect('https://just-dice.com/', {secure: true});

socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log("HI");
    socket.on('chat', function(txt, date) {
        console.log(txt);
    });
});
```

Why is it terminating?

Comment: Try to connect to: `wss://just-dice.com/`. And based on actual just-dice, they connect to: `wss://just-dice.com/socket.io/1/websocket/8yOUcoGZVBtQl5fxbfw-`

Comment: Actual just-dice does:  socket = io.connect(null, {secure: true});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by seeing if `socket.io` is throwing any errors:

```
socket.on('error', function (exception) {
    console.log(exception);
});
```

I'd also look to see if you're connecting to the right port. It's probable that the remote `socket.io` server is not on a default port.